# How to create complex object structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a structure of object using classes in javascript. I have a problem creating objects which involve nested structure. For example ..

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "mark",
    "phoneNumber" : "123456789",
    "dob" : "2010-08-20",
    "address" : {
        "latitude" : 123214.1231,
        "longitude" : 1231243.12,
        "houseNumber" : "1-2-3",
        "landmark" : "square-garden",
        "pinCode" : "134567876"
    }
}
```

`address` property has a separate inner structure. How to create a class for the above JSON?
I'm a bit new to JS. Please help me. Below are the things which I tried.

I have a class UserCreationDto

```
class UserCreationDto {

    id;
    name;
    phoneNumber;
    dob;
    address;

    constructor(id, name, phoneNumber, dob, address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and a class AddressDto

```
class AddressDto {

    latitude;
    longitude;
    houseNumber;
    landmark;
    pinCode;

    constructor(latitude, longitude, houseNumber, landmark, pinCode) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
        this.landmark = landmark;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }
}
```

I want `address` property of `UserCreationDto` to be of `AddressDto`. How can I do that? The above class `UserCreationDto` can be used.
But, there is no IntelliSense when i do

```
let userCreationDto = new UserCreationDto();
userCreationDto.address.{i-get-random-properties-here}
```

I have tried doing this

```
UserCreationDto.prototype.address=new AddressDto()
```

With the above approach, I got IntelliSense, but using a prototype, values are shared for all instances of `UserCreationDto`.

If I just continue with the above class `UserCreationDto`, then I don't get any IntelliSense.

IDEs allow anything to push to `address` property.

How to create nested structure as discussed above? What could be class structure?

Comment: `new UserCreationDto (1, 2, 3, 4, new AddressDto(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

Comment: @VLAZ How to write Class for that? Creating an object instance is fine. Help me in creating class.

Comment: You have created the classes. If you correctly instantiate them, then you'd get the correct data, as well. https://jsbin.com/vijeqoroqi/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ you are saying that above classes are fine. So, when i get an object like above from some http-post-request, first, i should create AddressDto , populate it. then create UserCreationDto and assign address property to already created AddressDto instance. This would work fine.

 Is there any way to get intellisense ? I mean , we get intellisense for id,name,phoneNumber,dob,address as they are straight properties of class. How to get intellisense over address's properties from userCreationDto Instance ?

Comment: @protonsphere What IDE are you using? You'll need to tell the intellisense that the `address` property is of type `AddressDto`.

Comment: @Bergi i'm using webstorm

Answer (score -1):

I think this way works, Instead of using class just use functions:

```
function AddressDto(latitude, longitude, houseNumber, landmark, pinCode) {
    this.latitude = latitude || 0;
    this.longitude = longitude || 0;
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber || '';
    this.landmark = landmark || '';
    this.pinCode = pinCode || '';
}
    
function UserCreationDto(id, name,phoneNumber, dob, address) {
    this.id = id || 0;
    this.name = name || '';
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber || '';
    this.dob = dob  || '';
    this.address = address || new AddressDto();
}

const user = new UserCreationDto();
user.id = 1;
user.name = 'test';
user.phoneNumber = '1234567890';
user.dob = '12/12/12';
console.log(user.address.latitude);
```

Thanks